# Why is there no () after we call decode_cvs in tensorflow(python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, so this might be a stupid question, but:
Why dont we use the calling parenthesis/pass arguments when call the decode_csv function, when defining dataset?

```py
CSV_COLUMNS = ['fare_amount', 'pickuplon','pickuplat','dropofflon','dropofflat','passengers', 'key']
LABEL_COLUMN = 'fare_amount'
DEFAULTS = [[0.0], [-74.0], [40.0], [-74.0], [40.7], [1.0], ['nokey']]

def read_dataset(filename, mode, batch_size = 512):
  def decode_csv(value_column):
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults = DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)
    return features, label

  # Create list of file names that match "glob" pattern (i.e. data_file_*.csv)
  filenames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filename)
  # Read lines from text files
  textlines_dataset = filenames_dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TextLineDataset)
  # Parse text lines as comma-separated values (CSV)
  dataset = textlines_dataset.map(decode_csv)

  # Note:
  # use tf.data.Dataset.flat_map to apply one to many transformations (here: filename -> text lines)
  # use tf.data.Dataset.map      to apply one to one  transformations (here: text line -> feature list)

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      num_epochs = None # indefinitely
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10 * batch_size)
  else:
      num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this

  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)

  return dataset
```

I am referring to this:

> dataset = textlines_dataset.map(decode_csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataset.map` function takes a function as an argument. When we come to consume the dataset the `decode_csv` will be called as needed.

Try to think of the Dataset API like a pipeline. The records going in to your `map(decode_csv)` operation are text lines but those comming out are the tuple of `features, label` but this mapping is not called up front. It is only called as needed when we consume the dataset.

Comment: so if I understand, we are just defining the function and pointing to it, but the Dataset API will take care of calling the function and running it accordingly?

Comment: @Beeeeeeer You may want to read about [first-class function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). Python as a language has first-class functions

Comment: @Beeeeeeer Yes, that understanding is essentially correct. And you're very welcome - hope it helps. If it does you can always upvote and/or accept ;-)

Comment: Lol I cant upvote, my reputation is under 15, but thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta, I think I am starting to understand, thanks